# Qual a diferença entre $var = function() e function var()?

Tags: php

Gostaria de saber, qual e a diferença entre:

```
<?php

$var = function() {
    return 5;
}

$var();
```

e...

```
<?php

function var() {
    return 5;
}

var();
```

Qual seria a diferença entre eles? Quando usá-los?

Comment: João Paulo, há mais alguma coisa que possa ser melhorado em alguma das respostas?

Comment: Não. Todos responderam claramente e simplificadamente para mim. Obrigado!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A primeira é uma [**função anônima**](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/functions.anonymous.php), enquanto a segunda é somente uma [**função definida**](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/functions.user-defined.php) pelo usuário.

Funções anônimas são úteis em situações onde seja necessário utilizar uma [função de retorno, *callback*](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.pseudo-types.php#language.types.callback), veja um exemplo:

```
$frutas = array('Maça', 'Banana', 'Perâ', 'Morango');

$funcao = function($fruta) {
    echo $fruta . "\n";
};

array_map($funcao, $frutas);
```

[Ver `demonstração`](http://ideone.com/kLz0A9)

**Nota**: Isso é válido se você tiver o PHP 5.3 ou superior, em versões anteriores, considere usar a função [`create_function`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.create-function.php).

Exemplo:

```
$frutas = array('Maça', 'Banana', 'Perâ', 'Morango');
$funcao = create_function('$fruta', 'echo $fruta . "\n";');

array_map($funcao, $frutas);
```

[Ver `demonstração`](http://ideone.com/S4EoBC)

Answer (score 7):

O que você tem no primeiro exemplo é uma [**função anônima**](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php), que é atribuída à variável `$var` e em seguida invocada. A variável tem nome, mas a função em si não tem.

No segundo caso, `var` é o nome da função (mas acho que é um nome ilegal, já que ["var" é uma palavra reservada](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.keywords.php) da linguagem). Tirando esse problema, seu segundo exemplo é o que se considera uma função comum, do tipo que sempre existiu na linguagem.

Já as funções anônimas foram introduzidas na versão 5.3 do PHP. Elas geralmente são usadas como *callbacks*, ou seja, passadas diretamente para outra função, que as executa quando (ou se) for necessário.

Exemplo (do manual):

```
echo preg_replace_callback('~-([a-z])~', function ($match) {
    return strtoupper($match[1]);
}, 'hello-world');
// outputs helloWorld
```

A função anônima é declarada no mesmo momento em que é passada para o `preg_replace_callback`, e executada para cada correspondência encontrada para a expressão regular no texto de entrada (`'hello-world'`).